# Why would you disable 'Always On' on an azure app service instance?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service

As far as I can tell, it doesn't cost more to have 'always on' enabled, and it avoids the response rate when an app is unloaded, so why would anyone disable it?

Answer (score 2):

One reason would be to save resources on the instance(s) if the apps go idle often. The processes are constantly using up memory if Always On is enabled.

Of course there's also the minimal overhead of the HTTP requests that it sends to your app.

I might also disable it if the app only contains a WebJob that I trigger externally once in a while. In that case the app does not need to be running all the time.

Comment: in addition to that, it interferes with the way profiling applications works such as New Relic.

Answer (score 0):

It actually does cost more if you don't need it because you can downgrade from the Standard tier to the Basic tier which is cheaper, and sacrifices access to the Always On option.